# Yum on Centos 8 - Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'

Tags: linux, centos, yum, centos8, rhel8

I'm on a fresh Centos 8 install and have tried to use yum for the first time (on this machine). I get the following for any attempt to install or update anything:

```
yum update
CentOS-8 - AppStream                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
```

Port 80 is open although nmap reports it as closed presumably because I haven't yet installed apache. To be double sure I have added port 80 to firewalld which is confirmed:

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
25/tcp 80/tcp
```

I have tried various advice like yum clean and clearing the yum cache but nothing helps.

This is what is in the dnf.log:

```
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z INFO --- logging initialized ---
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DDEBUG timer: config: 4 ms
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DEBUG Loaded plugins: builddep, changelog, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache, needs-restarting, playground, repoclosure, repodiff, repograph, repomanage, reposync
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DEBUG DNF version: 4.2.7
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DDEBUG Command: yum install httpd 
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DDEBUG Installroot: /
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DDEBUG Releasever: 8
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DEBUG cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DDEBUG Base command: install
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DDEBUG Extra commands: ['install', 'httpd']
2020-03-30T19:33:01Z DEBUG repo: downloading from remote: AppStream
2020-03-30T19:33:02Z DEBUG error: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org] (http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock).
2020-03-30T19:33:02Z DEBUG Cannot download 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org].
2020-03-30T19:33:02Z ERROR Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
2020-03-30T19:33:02Z DDEBUG Cleaning up.
2020-03-30T19:33:02Z SUBDEBUG 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 552, in load
    ret = self._repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/repo.py", line 394, in load
    return _repo.Repo_load(self)
RuntimeError: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 65, in main
    return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 98, in _main
    return cli_run(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 114, in cli_run
    cli.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 1134, in run
    self._process_demands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 832, in _process_demands
    load_available_repos=self.demands.available_repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 406, in fill_sack
    self._add_repo_to_sack(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 136, in _add_repo_to_sack
    repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 558, in load
    raise dnf.exceptions.RepoError(str(e))
dnf.exceptions.RepoError: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
2020-03-30T19:33:02Z CRITICAL Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
```

Comment: turns out my resolv.conf file didn't have any Nameservers.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently not the problem here, but if you have [pinned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426267/how-to-upgrade-from-centos-7-2-to-7-3-and-not-up-to-7-4) yourself to CentOS 8.1.1911 you will get the same error until you re-point your /etc/yum.repos.d/ repositories at http://vault.centos.org instead of http://mirror.centos.org

Comment: How can I do that? That would be very useful

Comment: @mordack550 I've added a link to my answer that gives an example of pinning.  It can be a little tricky, but vault.centos.org is the key.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be connected to the Internet in order to download packages.

Check that you have an IP address (with `ip a`), that you have a default route (with `ip r`), and that you have nameservers defined so you can resolve names (with `cat /etc/resolv.conf`).

Comment: Strange, this got a downvote with no explanation despite the OP saying that it was actually the answer. Why is that?

Comment: Probably for saying "you need the internet to download packages", lol.

Answer (score 3):

In the name of ALLAH.
I think that This problem reseon is for End of Life of centos version..

```
CentOS Linux 7 EOL: 2024-06-30
CentOS Linux 8 EOL: 2021-12-31
CentOS Stream 8 EOL: 2024-05-31
CentOS Stream 9 EOL: estimated 2027, dependent on RHEL9 end of “Full Support Phase”
```

So I Migrating from CentOS Linux 8 to CentOS Stream.

notice than your server  must be fresh.
In the operating environment it is associated with risk.

#dnf install centos-release-stream

#dnf swap centos-{linux,stream}-repos

#dnf distro-sync

instruction is in this url:
https://www.tecmint.com/migrate-centos-8-to-centos-stream/

Comment: Uhm, no. While it is true that CentOS 8 is EOL now, it was not true in March 2020, when the question was asked. This was a different problem.

Comment: I had this issue today, and for me this was the issue; It got resolved by switching to Centos 8 Stream. This can be done : 
```dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
dnf distro-sync```

Comment: @SvennD is right it also worked for me except I had to add a `;` to his command to threat it as 2 commands: `dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos; dnf distro-sync`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message when installing PHP. It was caused by the network configuration: after changing the gateway address in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0 the problem was solved.
Probably caused by changing from DHCP to a static IP-Address. The information in my internet-router was misleading. I just used the first address in my LAN, in my case: 192.168.11.1. It is the address of the management-console of my router.

Answer (score 0):

the problem solved in a clean new installation of centos stream 8 after I checked out and disabled from software repositories some repositories that checked in error.

Images below
[from software repositories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4edo.png)

[list 1st,2nd,3rd page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Joa12.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbACM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I faced a similar situation while updating my centos and installing a few packages.

**Migrate from CentOS 8 to CentOS Stream 8:**

```
dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos

dnf distro-sync
```

It will help you resolve your [issue](https://www.hacktoday.com/centos-8-fix-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo-appstream/).