# unable to install openssh server on centos 8

Tags: centos8

**Image**: Centos 8

**Downloaded** from osboxes

**Goal**: Installation of any package for example openssh server

**error:** [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l6vr.jpg)

I have checked the following solutions [centos yum](https://serverfault.com/questions/1010136/yum-on-centos-8-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo-appstream#new-answer?newreg=f66ea8976ac34bdfb1ca3ee31ea977d2)

But did not really help me in any respect.

I am stuck and surprised i am not sure what can be done. I have been researching on this issue for a while now.

Please help

Regards

s

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault! Try not to post pictures of text. The error message is `could not resolve host mirrorlist.centos.org`, which you could have added to your question in text form. You could also have accessed the server using SSH and simply copy-pasted your commands and their output.

Comment: The error means that name resolution of your Centos server doesn't work correctly; either no DNS servers are configured, or they are incorrect.

Comment: @berndbausch unfortunately i am unable to ssh to this server i have checked the network it is a bridge network ..

Comment: Could it be that the same problem that prevents you from accessing the server also prevents the server from accessing DNS servers or mirrorlist.centos.org?

Comment: @berndbausch yes i feel the same i have done everything what i can think off

Comment: I can only help if I know how the virtual machine is connected to the network. Please describe your setup. Which VM hypervisor do you use? Does the VM  have an IP address? Is this IP address in the same subnet as the virtual machine host's? Can you ping to the VM or from the VM?

Comment: @berndbausch 

Set up : this is a vm hosted vmworkstation. it has got a bridged network. I am unable to ping the machine.

Comment: How did the VM get its IP address? Is the IP address in the same subnet as the hypervisor host's? To be honest, I have no idea how to troubleshoot VMware Workstation, but it is clear that the VM's network connection is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Your VM's network settings are most likely incorrect as DNS lookups don't work and you can't connect to the VM in question. Verify that your box's configuration is correct.